# Increase size of poster in a0poster

Tags: posters, a0poster

I am designing a poster for OHBM conference (my first poster). I am using `a0poster`, but it gives posters of fixed width and height.

I want to make a poster of 90 cm width, and 150 cm height. Is there a way to do this in `a0poster`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\setlength{\paperwidth}{90cm}` and `\setlength{\paperheight}{150cm}`. Here you can find the [`a0poster` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/a0poster?lang=de).

Size:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[portrait,a0b,posterdraft]{a0poster}
\usepackage{german,epsf,pstricks}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{90cm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{150cm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will there be any change in font size?

Comment: I don't think so.